# Updating FromDate and ToDate columns in table

Tags: mysql, date, stored-procedures

I have a MySQL table in which I have two columns `Fromdate` and `Todate`. When ever I execute the stored procedure in MySQL, I want to update the `fromdate` and `todate` in the above table as next date.

For example

- `@Fromdate` is 09/04/2016 15:00:00
- `@Todate` is 09/04/2016 23:59:59

It should be updated to:

- `@Fromdate` = 09/05/2016 00:00:00
- `@Todate` = 09/05/2016 23:59:59

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS: and you can do it with your own selected date as well

```
UPDATE test_table 
SET 
    from_date = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00"),
    to_date = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59")
```

and you add rest of conditions whatever you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Update yourtable set fromdate=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'),todate=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59') where <<condition>>
```

Comment: How can I take from date as GETDATE()+00:00:00 and To date as GETDATE()+23:59:59

Comment: @Ravi first GETDATE is not available in MySQL and second if you add +1 then it will return next day's date which is not the requirement. The todate must be same day's date with EOD time.